# How do I click a link on a web page using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm writing VBA code to obtain a ticker symbol from a user, navigate to a website, input the ticker symbol and click the appropriate link.

I researched this [StackOverflow question and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002756/how-to-click-on-a-hyperlink-on-a-web-page-using-vba-excel), however, I don't have an innertext value to utilize.

My VBA code:

```
Sub clicklick()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ticker = InputBox("Enter Ticker Symbol: ")

With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate ("http://www.SITE_URL.com")

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

ie.document.getElementsbyName("sSrchTerm").Item.innertext = ticker

End With
End Sub
```

The link appears as follows in the page source:

```
<a class="hqt_button" href="javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()"></a>
```

The element doesn't seem to have a name, innertext or id. How can I click the link?

EDIT:

```
    Set Link = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a") 
    For Each l In Link 
        If Link.classname = "hqt_button" Then 
            Link.Click 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next l
```

Comment: `GetElementsByTagTame("a")`, then iterate that collection checking to ensure that the element's `.href` is consistent and/or the class is "hqt_button"?

Comment: class = "hqt_button", href= "javascript:void(0):..."

Comment: So something like the Edit above.

Comment: I think you're on the right track but try `If l.classname = "hqt_button" Then...`  and then you need `Next l` or simply `Next` -- not `Next link`.

Comment: Made those changes, but got a Run-time 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.  Doesn't seem to like this line of code:If link.classname = "hqt_button" Then

Comment: It works, had to change link to l for both l.classname and l.click.  If you care to submit a formal answer, I be happy to give you the check mark.  Really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: ahh yes I forgot to mention `l.Click`.  I will write an answer for you. Glad I could help!

Comment: I know this is an old thread but does anyone care to elaborate on what "l" or "Link" are defined or declared as?  Its not too clear and I need to do something similar and am getting the same Run time error 438.  Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try getting the collection of anchor tags, with:

```
GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

Then, iterate that collection using as much logic as you can to ensure you're clicking the right button.

```
For each l in ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a") 
    If l.ClassName = "hqt_button" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    Next
```

If there are multiple anchors with the same classname, you could do:

```
    If l.ClassName = "hqt_button" AND l.Href = ""javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    Next
```

**Alternatively**

If you are using IE9+ you could use the `GetElementsByClassName` method.

```
GetElementsByClassName("hqt_button")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) of

```
a.hqt_button[href='javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()']
```

The `"."` means className. `[]` encloses an attribute. The above says className `hqt_button` with attribute `href` with value `'javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()'`, inside of an `a` tag.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**Syntax in VBA:**

CSS selectors are applied via the `.querySelector` method of the HTMLDocument.

```
ie.document.querySelector("a.hqt_button[href='javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()']").Click
```