# How to click an HTML button using VBA?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Below is the HTML code on a site I am trying to scrape. The button on the screen is "Book Now" but a as I understand a Span is not clickable so I am trying to click "btn search-btn " with the VBA code below:-

```
Set AvailableLinks = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")

    AvailableLinks.Click
```

With above code I receive the error "object does not support property or method"
Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
</table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions clearfix">
                                <a class="btn search-btn ">
                                    <span class="end"></span>
                                    <span class="tile">Book Now</span>
                                    <span class="start ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle"></span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="validation-error ">
```

Comment: try with this:  `AvailableLinks(0).Click`

Comment: @Kazimierz Jawor Thanks. Using AvaibleLinks(0).Click I no longer receive the object error and my code runs but the code does not click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shahin Any ideas?

Comment: check this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639357/2143262).

Comment: @Anthony , try the one suggested by Kazimierz Jawor following the link he has already provided. Usually that method works most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

@Kazimierz Jawor Thank you the following code works:-

```
For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
If l.className = "btn search-btn" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
```