# I want to call a specific function on an internal website

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to click or call the function "Titlebar_simple_search" as shown on picture from VBA in Excel. It is on an intranet page on my workplace. I know I am far from the goal, but I am wondering if I can get some advice where to start.

Is HTMLdoc the best way?
Should I first call the body class or div class that the function is located inside?

Any help is appreciated

[print scrn from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJp8Q.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim IE As Object

 Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

   IE.Visible = True

 Url = "https://urlremovedduetoprivacy"

   IE.Navigate Url

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
HTMLdoc.getElementById("simple_search_link").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use excel vba to click a link on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638533/how-do-i-use-excel-vba-to-click-a-link-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to navigate a frame first and then get the element by its id:

```
Ie.document.getElementsByName("titlebar")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("simple_search_link").click
```